# How to create a new python list based on index of a recurring element in python List

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working with a python list which looks like-

```
['',  'tenantspace', 'SYSCode', 'CodeName', 'AttributeValue2', 'AttrDate', '',  'tenantspace', 'SYSCode', 'CodeName', 'AttributeValue2', 'AttrDate', '',  'tenantspace', 'SYSCode', 'CodeName', 'AttributeValue3', 'AttrDate', '',  'tenantspace', 'SYSCode', 'CodeName', 'AttributeValue4', 'AttrDate']
```

It is the repletion of below elements (guaranteed) with 'SYSCode' being a fixed value in entire list.

```
'',  'tenantspace', 'SYSCode', 'CodeName', 'AttributeValue', 'AttrDate'
```

I am looking to create a new list which would only have below elements in it. Since 'SYSCode' is a fixed value in entire list, I am trying to use it as an index. AttributeValue is guaranteed to be at SYSCode Index + 2. How do I retrieve below as another list?

```
['AttributeValue1','AttributeValue2','AttributeValue3','AttributeValue4']
```

Comment: I think you may need to clarify your requirements. ```AttributeValue4``` does not appear in your input list. What exactly are the criteria that result in ```AttributeValue4``` appearing in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with list comprehension:

```
ls = ['',  'tenantspace', 'SYSCode', 'CodeName', 'AttributeValue1', 'AttrDate', '',  'tenantspace', 'SYSCode', 'CodeName', 'AttributeValue2', 'AttrDate', '',  'tenantspace', 'SYSCode', 'CodeName', 'AttributeValue3', 'AttrDate', '',  'tenantspace', 'SYSCode', 'CodeName', 'AttributeValue4', 'AttrDate']

res = [ls[i + 2] for i in range(len(ls)) if ls[i] == 'SYSCode']
```

Result would look like:

```
['AttributeValue1', 'AttributeValue2', 'AttributeValue3', 'AttributeValue4']
```

Comment: The original list contains ```AttributeValue1``` elements. I think the question is asking how to convert them sequentially to ```AttributeValueX```.

Comment: @sj95126 That wouldn't make sense at all, since he mentioned `SYSCode` is a fixed value while others might not

Comment: The input data at the top of the question has ```AttributeValue1``` repeated. It does not match what's in your solution.

Comment: I got your point but as I said it wouldn't make any sense with the statement he made. I will edit answer if OP clarifies what exactly needed

Comment: I've asked the OP for a clarification, but part of my point is that ```AttributeValue4``` does not appear in the input data in the question but **does** appear in the input data of your answer. Either the question or the answer changed the data set.

Comment: Apologies everyone, repeated AttributeValue1 was a manual copy paste error. I had to mask this confidential data. The answer above solved my issue, exactly what I was trying to get